# Import from Windows to Linux

Tags: migration, import, linux, iis

The previous IIS server used to host this WP site. Now I have a Linux environment. The Db import went smoothly. Copying over the site files generates issues however. There are plugins that refuse to start. I understand the issues with paths. Those are fixed.

My question: is there a import script/function that is the "proper" way to migrate from Windows IIS to Linux Apache?

Edit: one of the offending plugins is stored in a dir named: ist-form-dresser
I cant find a plugin thats named that. Anyone know which one this is?

Comment: It might be easier to install a fresh new copy of WordPress (making sure it's the same version as before) and install the themes and plugins, then migrate the database back in. That way you'll be sure the files are in the right places, with the right encoding, and the right permissions.

Comment: I agree with making a fresh copy. But if you did want help fixing your plugins that refuse to start you'll have to give us more details e.g. error messages from the UI or from your logs.

Comment: @WebElaine trouble is: I did not control the IIS server, all I have is a zip file with all the data and instructions a la: here make this work :(. I'm new to WP. not new to linux. I edited the question.

Comment: @Rup I edited the question. Also there are other plugins with issues. But one at a time :) Thanks for the help!

Comment: Some of them might be written specifically for your site, or supplied with your theme. I'd look for ist-form-dresser in your theme folders, or if not you're going to have to fix it up yourself then.

Comment: @Rup thanks, makes more sense now!

Comment: no script should be necessary, PHP accepts `/` in both windows and Linux, and the migration should be a standard file and database copy. If a folder is missing then you must not have copied it or it was never there to begin with

Comment: @TomJNowell looks like its missing in the source zip... sigh now the emails begin. Thanks